# Is it possible to convert a Wordpress plugin to separate PHP script?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I have a Wordpress booking plugin, which has a booking form frontend and dasboard. I would like to know if it's possible to convert a Wordpress plugin to separate PHP script?

Comment: Would someone telling you that it's possible or not stop you from trying to figure it out?  SO is for _specific, code-related_ questions.  Have at it and come on back when you get stuck. :)

Comment: You should have knowledge of PHP and WordPress. Then you will be able to convert each line of code into PHP. I don't think that there's some plugin that can do this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible? Sure. Easy? Probably not.

The snag is that any WordPress plugin runs off the back of plenty of built-in WordPress functions. From low level (retrieving the site URL) to higher level (accepting inputs, saving data, etc).

If the plugin was very simple, you might try to go through it piece by piece and dissect it from the WordPress backbone that it runs on, but it would be pretty slow going. What I might try instead is use the plugin as a reference point to write your own script.